# Passing res.locals variable to GoggleMaps breaks initMap function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, express

I am having a problem with the Google Map initMap function. I am using Express and trying to pass an array of locations to make markers on the map. When I pass the variable set to the locations to the script in the view it breaks the initMap function and I get the error: initMap is not a function, calling to the deferred script that uses initMap as its callback. However, if I remove the locations variable, the map loads properly just without any markers. Here is my code:

```
<script>
        window.initMap = function() {
        var userLocation = {lat: 40.7410986, lng: -73.9888682};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: userLocation
        });
          var locations = <%=JSON.stringify(locations)%>
          console.log(locations)

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          for(let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
          return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably would have yielded a JS error (so it's always worth checking your browser's JS console).

Instead of using `<%= ... %>` (which does HTML/XML-type escaping), use `<%- ... %>` to produce [unescaped output](https://github.com/mde/ejs/blob/1c7e3659c611ecbfe3ee2e5fd3ed355434479932/docs/syntax.md#--unescaped-output):

```
var locations = <%- JSON.stringify(locations) %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was checking the console but wasn't getting anything that pointed to that.